# No ClassTag available for T

Tags: scala

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.reflect.ClassTag  

class TestRDD[T: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T]) extends JavaRDD(rdd)
```

This statement is accepted from the console. However at compile time the following error is thrown:

```
No ClassTag available for T
[error] class TestRDD[T: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T]) extends JavaRDD(rdd)
[error]                ^
[error] one error found
[error] (jobs/it:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
class TestRDD[T](rdd: List[T])(implicit c: ClassTag[T]) extends JavaRDD(rdd)
```

use `implicit` to auto implicit the `ClassTag` of generic **T**.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is the embarassing solution:

```
class TestRDD[T: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T]) extends RDD[T](rdd: RDD[T])
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to jvm template type erase, the compiler can't get type information of `T` from `rdd`.

But type information of `T` is stored in class `RDD`, maybe you can get the classtag of `T` from `RDD` class